# C# - How to add a List property to a Class and add property values

Tags: c#, list, class, object, oop

These are my instructions:

- Create a property in the Book class called Distributors. This property should be a list of type Distributor.
- Add the 3 distributors you created to any of the 5 book class objects you created initially.

After adding, `distributors1` to `book`, I tried checking the book by doing:

```
book.Distributors(distributor1);
Console.WriteLine(book);
```

and I get no errors when I run but my WriteLine does not spit out my book with the added distributor so I'm pretty sure I did this incorrectly.

What is the correct way to add a List property of Distributors to my Book class? Also, once I add the list property to my Book class how would I correctly add `distributor1` to `book`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Book
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Author { get; set; }

        public int Year { get; set; }

        public string CoverType { get; set; }

        public List<Distributor> Distributors(Distributor distributor)
        {
        List<Distributor> newList = new List<Distributor>();
        newList.Add(distributor);
        return newList;
        }

        public Book(string title, string author, int year, string coverType)
        {
            this.Title = title;
            this.Author = author;
            this.Year = year;
            this.CoverType = coverType;
        }
        
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            var book = new Book("Art of War", "Sun Tzu", 1999, "Hard");

            var location1 = new Location("123 Sesame St", "Fake City", "CA", "92604");
            var distributor1 = new Distributor("Big Bird", location1);
           
            book.Distributors.Add(distributor1);  

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `Distributors` is a _method_ (a function), NOT a property. That method _returns a value_, which you are throwing away.

Comment: There's a lot of code posted here that doesn't matter to your issue. Can you remove those lines? Look into making a [mre].

Comment: so would adding just this 'public List<Distributor> Distributors { get; set; }' work ?

Comment: Suggested Reading: **[Guidelines for Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections)**

Answer (score 1):

Note; the question has been edited since the answer was written. In the previous iteration of the question the Distributors member was defined as:

```
    public List<Distributor> Distributors(Distributor distributor)
    {
        List<Distributor> newList = new List<Distributor>();
        newList.Add(distributor);
        return newList;
    }
```

---

Your CoverType (for example) is a property (of type string)

Distributors wouldn't really look any different:

```
public List<Distributor> Distributors { get; set; } = new();
```

..except that it's sensible to make a new one as part of initializing the class, because otherwise you'll get a null reference exception if you try and use it. In modern c# you don't need to specify the type on the right if the compiler can see it on the left. If your c# is older you'll need to use `new List<Distributor>();`

You add like you would any normal list; call on the property and add a Distributor:

```
someBook.Distributors.Add(someDistributor);
```

Comment: Do I have to initialize it in the Book constructor with **this.Distributors = new List<Distributor>();** ? or does doing this **List<Distributor> Distributors { get; set; } = new List<Distributor>();** take care of it?

Comment: this didn't work. I tried it then used a for each loop to **Console.WriteLine** the **items** in my **book.Distributors** list and nothing comes up.

Comment: Nevermind it does work. I just used **Console.WriteLine(book.Distributors.Count);** instead to check if a distributor was added and it spit out 1 which is correct. If someone else can explain how I can correctly WriteLine my **book.Distributor** that would be awesome.

Comment: Constructor or setting it new on the line where it is declared amounts to the same thing. As a method that is run automatically upon making `new` the constructor can perform more involved logic than what is possible on the line where the property is declared but initializers can be used to prefill collections with data. `public List<string> X {get;set;}= new { "Hello","world"}` would prefill a list of strings with two strings, for example

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem in writing `foreach(var d in book.Distributors) Console.WriteLine(d.Name);` or or `book.Distributors.ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine(d.Name))`. You can even `book.Distributors.ForEach(Console.WriteLine)` if you have overridden the ToString method to print out some rendering of a distributor

Comment: I can see in your deleted answer that you tried calling Console.WriteLine inside the foreach loop but you said "nothing shows up" - that wasn't strictly accurate; something did show up it's just not what you were expecting. You called `Console.WriteLine(item)`  where item was a distributor, and "ConsoleApp.Distributor" was printed - this is exactly expected if you don't write eg `public override string ToString() { return some_string_here;}`. In c# everything descends from `object` and object has a ToString that returns the *type* of the object - ConsoleApp.Distributor. Because you didn't

Comment: provide any more specific version that eg returns the name and address etc, passing the distributor into Console.WriteLine causes WriteLine to treat it as an object and print out whatever ToString returns, which in the default state is just the name of the type. Either be more specific about what you want to print - `Console.WriteLine(item.Name)` or provide a ToString override that replaces the default one with something that returns a more descriptive string